# R - winDialogString equivalent in tcltk (tkdialog?)

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

**What's the equivalent to winDialogString in tcltk?**

---

#### Background

I've been using `readline` in R in order to ask the user a question and get a response:

```
response <- readline("What's the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow? ")
```

Today I was on my Windows laptop and discovered the `winDialogString` function, which pops up a little modal message box to get the input:

```
response <- winDialogString("What's the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow? ",
                            default="african or european?")
```

I wish to use this function, but in the interests of portability, I'd like to use a `tcltk` version of `winDialog` so at least my Linux boxes can also have this.

Now, if I was using `winDialog` the equivalent is `tkmessageBox`:

```
# fairly equivalent, tkmessageBox is more portable.
winDialog(type='yesno','Do you like green eggs and ham?')
tkmessageBox(type='yesno',message='Do you like green eggs and ham?')
```

**What's the equivalent to winDialogString in tcltk?**

I thought it was `tkdialog`, so I gave it a go:

```
tkdialog("What's the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow?")
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error in structure(.External("dotTclObjv", objv, PACKAGE = "tcltk"), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] wrong # args: should be "tk_dialog w title text bitmap default ...".
```

The documentation is quite unhelpful `?tkdialog` points to a generic tk help page with no specific documentation. How can I use `tkdialog` (and is it even what I want?)

I deduced that I might have to feed in all the arguments it's complained about, so I've tried a few things :

```
> tkdialog(title='',
           text="What's the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
           bitmap='',default="african or european?")
Error in structure(.External("dotTclObjv", objv, PACKAGE = "tcltk"), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] bad window path name "-title".

> tkdialog(tktoplevel(),title='',
           text="What's the air speed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
           bitmap='',default="african or european?")
Error in structure(.External("dotTclObjv", objv, PACKAGE = "tcltk"), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] bitmap "-text" not defined.
```

How can I get this to work? I'd rather stay within `tcltk` rather than using something like `gWidgets`, since `tcltk` is in most R distros (and if the R  distro is `tcltk`-incompatible, I'll fall back to `readline`).

cheers.

Comment: Not sure you'll find one. For ginput in gWidgetstcltk I had to build my own. https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2tcltk/blob/master/R/dialogs.R

Comment: That's a shame. I'd still like to know how to use `tkdialog` though. (That is an impressive set of functions, thanks for sharing! I'd one day like to share my personal package of utility functions I've written for R)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're after is indeed `tkdialog` but it's not really designed for use from R; you'll have to do some work (and I fully admit to not knowing R, I'm on the Tk side of things). What I can do is explain what those parameters need to be.

There is documentation of the underlying `tk_dialog` command [online](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/dialog.htm). In particular, you need:

1. A window name which is not used for anything else. (This will become the name of the window used to implement the dialog.)
2. A title for the dialog.
3. Some text for the body of the dialog.
4. The string name of a bitmap picture to use. Unless you're doing something very gnarly and low-level, must be one of: `error`, `gray75`, `gray50`, `gray25`, `gray12`, `hourglass`, `info`, `questhead`, `question`, `warning` (or on OSX, you also get these bonus system pictures: 
   `document`,
   `stationery`,
   `edition`,
   `application`,
   `accessory`,
   `folder`,
   `pfolder`,
   `trash`,
   `floppy`,
   `ramdisk`,
   `cdrom`,
   `preferences`,
   `querydoc`,
   `stop`,
   `note`,
   `caution`).
5. The zero-based index of the default button. If -1, there's no default.
6. (Well, 6, 7, ...) The text to put on the buttons, one string per button.

The API isn't really all that well designed to be used from R. It's not particularly nice from Tcl either, and that list of bitmaps is *really* obscure (and that's speaking as one of the maintainers of Tk). In case you're interested, the list *is* [documented](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetBitmap.htm) but I'm not surprised you didn't know that that was what you wanted. I wouldn't tell you about it except that you're using `tk_dialog` (itself obsolete really).

---

You could also implement it all yourself. The code to do a simple dialog isn't that complex (`tk_dialog` is purely scripted on top of conventional features). I'm not nearly a good enough R programmer to be able to help you do it though.

Comment: Those arguments are _all positional_, not named. Yes, this is different to the rest of Tk. No, we're not changing it.

Comment: Thanks - based on your answer, the key was to **not provide any named arguments**: `tkdialog('.windowname','title',"What's the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?",'question',-1,'african','european')` produces a dialogue with one button per solution option. Do you know of a tk command that will give a text box allowing user input? Otherwise I will do as you say and just implement one of my own.

Comment: Had a quick look through the documentation you linked for a text entry modal dialog box - looks like I'll have to make my own. Thanks so much.